# The operation CreateSession failed due to an internal error: Could not initialize class mono.android..D3DImageFactory

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

[Click this image to show error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aPvC.png)

I am new to Xamarin . I want tO learn xamarin. I have following installation on my machine.
1. Visual Studio Community 2017
2. Xamarin latest
I have updated the Android SDK 25 but still getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that Visual Studio is pointing to the 64-bit version of the JDK rather than 32-bit.

Select `Tools` > `Options` from the top menu and scroll all the way to the bottom on the left hand side list and open `Xamarin` > `Android Settings`. In there you should change the first item, "Java Development Kit Location" as highlighted in the picture below.

[image]

In your case it's probably pointing to a folder in `Program Files (x86)`. Try to find the `Java\jdkx.x.x_xxx folder` in `Program Files\` instead like you can see in the picture.

After making the change, close the axml designer and reload the file. It should work after that.